# splice function does not work properly in 1 items array

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In my Laravel 5/vuejs 2/ vuex app I make deletion of an row in db and use splice function to remove item from the array as:

```
    axios({
        method: ( 'delete' ),
        url: this.getters.apiUrl + '/personal/hostel_bookmarks/' + this.getters.currentLoggedUser.id + "/" + relatedHostel.id,
    }).then((response) => {
        let L = this.getters.hostelBookmarks.length

        for (var I = 0; I < L; I++) {
            if (relatedHostel.id == this.getters.hostelBookmarks[I].hostel_id) {
                // this.getters.hostelBookmarks.splice(this.getters.hostelBookmarks.indexOf(this.getters.hostelBookmarks[I]), 1)                        
                this.getters.hostelBookmarks.splice(I, 1)
                context.commit('refreshHostelBookmarks', this.getters.hostelBookmarks);
                break;
            }
        }
        bus.$emit( 'onHostelBookmarkDeleteSuccess', response );
    }).catch((error) => {
        bus.$emit('onHostelBookmarkDeleteFailure', error);
    });
```

It works ok if this.getters.hostelBookmarks has more 1 elements, but if it has only 1 items then it is not deleted, but how error in js console...

How to fix ?

Comment: Array.splice works as expected also with an array with one item in the array, i.e. the array becomes empty. Rather the code fails because you're changing the array while iterating it, when removing an item from the array, `I` doesn't correspond to the indices of the array anymore.

Comment: use filter instead of splice. `array.filter ( item => item.id != some_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code?

```
let L = this.getters.hostelBookmarks.length;

for (var I = L-1; I >= 0; I--) {
    if (relatedHostel.id == this.getters.hostelBookmarks[I].hostel_id) {
        this.getters.hostelBookmarks.splice(I, 1);
        context.commit('refreshHostelBookmarks', this.getters.hostelBookmarks);
        break;
    }
}
```

demo code for ++, --:
If you have an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. And you want to remove the 2nd and 4th element, 2 and 4.

First ++:

```
const origin = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(var i = 0; i < origin.length; i++){
    if(i === 1 || i === 3) {
        origin.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(origin); // [1, 3, 4]
```

As you can see, the result is not you expected. If you log the every element in loop, you will see the index of element was changed after the element ***2*** was deleted. When i is 3 in the loop, actually, the 5th element will be deleted.

Then let's have a look in --:

```
const origin = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(var i = origin.length; i >= 0; i--){
    if(i === 3 || i === 1) {
        origin.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(origin); // [1, 3, 5]
```

This is what you want. When --, we will remove the element from the last to the first. The index of element is not changed.

Answer (score 2):

This should fix your problem

```
let index = this.getters.hostelBookmarks.findIndex(item => { return item.hostel_id === relatedHostel.id })
if (index !== -1) {
  this.getters.hostelBookmarks.splice(index, 1)
  context.commit('refreshHostelBookmarks', this.getters.hostelBookmarks); 
}
```

Comment: the same issue :
this.getters.hostelBookmarks.splice(index, 1)

 does not work when index=1 and hostelBookmarks has only 1 element

Comment: @PetroGromovo when there is only 1 item, **index will be 0** and **NOT 1**. so splice will be : `splice(0,1)`. This is so because index of arrays is 0 based. I hope you are aware of that and taking that into consideration...